# Как сверстать данные блоки?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как сверстать блоки как на изображении?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, это поможет :)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-grid;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.item p {
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.big-item-a {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.big-item-b {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.small-item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big-item-a item"><p>some text</p></div>
  <div class="small-item item"><p>some text</p></div>
  <div class="small-item item"><p>some text</p></div>
  <div class="small-item item"><p>some text</p></div>
  <div class="small-item item"><p>some text</p></div>
  <div class="small-item item"><p>some text</p></div>
  <div class="small-item item"><p>some text</p></div>
  <div class="big-item-b item"><p>some text</p></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gorbaghramyan/p0ayx761/67/

Comment: думал просто подскажут направление, а тут еще и сверстали)) Большое спасибо!

Comment: хорошего дня :)